# Drupal alternative to PHP's strip_tags?

Tags: 7

Is there a Drupal 7 function that is equivalent to PHP strip_tags?

Answer (score 3):

Drupal 7 uses `strip_tags` directly in plenty of places (theme.inc, common.inc, etc.).

If there was an equivalent, core would use that instead, so you can safely assume that you should use `strip_tags` when you need the functionality it provides, not a Drupal-specific method.

Answer (score 0):

AsciiDoc filter will work like strip_tags 
https://www.drupal.org/project/asciidoc

Not Exactly, but many cases it will work like strip_tags.